# Problems mounting a S3 bucket with s3fs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mount, s3fs

I am trying to mount a S3 bucket on an AWS EC2 instance following this [instruction](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Installation-Notes). I was able to install the dependencies via `yum`, followed by cloning the git repository, and then making and installing the `s3fs` tool.

Furthermore, I ensured my `AWSACCESSKEYID` and `AWSSECRETACCESSKEY` values were in several locations (because I could not get the tool to work and searching for an answer suggest placing the file in different locations).

- ~/.passwd-s3fs
- /etc/.passwd-s3fs
- ~/.bash_profile

For the `.passwd-s3fs` I have set the permissions as follows.

```
chmod 600 ~/.passwd-s3fs
chmod 640 /etc/.passwd-s3fs
```

Additionally, the `.passwd-s3fs` files have the content as suggested in this format: `AWSACCESSKEYID`:`AWSSECRETACCESSKEY`.

I have also logged out and in just to make sure the changes take effect. When I execute this command `/usr/bin/s3fs bucketname /mnt`, I get the following response.

```
s3fs: MOUNTPOINT: /mnt permission denied.
```

When I run the same command with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo /usr/bin/s3fs mybucket /mnt`, I get the following message.

```
s3fs: could not determine how to establish security credentials.
```

I am using `s3fs` v1.84 on the following AMI `ami-0ff8a91507f77f867` (Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0.20180811 x86_64 HVM GP2). From the AWS Console for S3, my bucket's name is NOT `mybucket` but something just as simple (I am wondering if there's anything special I have to do with naming).

Additionally, my AWS access and secret key pair is generated from the IAM web interface and placed into the admin group (having `AdministratorAccess` policy) defined below.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on what's going on? Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After tinkering a bit, I found the following helps.

```
/usr/bin/s3fs mybucket /mnt -o passwd_file=.passwd-s3fs -o allow_other
```

Note that I specify the `.passwd-s3fs` file's location. And also note that I allow others to view the mount. Additionally, I had to modify /etc/fuse.conf to enable `user_allow_other`.

```
# mount_max = 1000
user_allow_other
```

To test, I typed in `touch /mnt/README.md` and then observed the file in my S3 bucket (web UI).

I am a little disappointed that this problem is not better documented. I would have expected the default home location or `/etc` to be where the `.passwd-s3fs` file would be looked by the tool, but that's not the case. Additionally, `sudo` (as suggested by a link I did not bookmark) forces the tool to look in `~/home/root`, which does not exists.

Comment: You should add a subdirectory to `/mnt`. Something like `/mnt/my-bucket`. And use that as mountpoint. Cause `/mnt` is sometimes used to mount other devices too.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was mismatch in IAM profile while mounting and IAM profile of ec2 server.

EC2 was launched with **role2** and I was mouting with

```
/usr/local/bin/s3fs -o allow_other mybucket /mnt/s3fs/mybucketfolder -o iam_role='role1'
```

which dit not through any error but did not mounted.

PS

I do not have any access keys or s3 password file on ec2 server.